# nested attributes are doubling while updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My current problems can be sum up in the title: i'm using nested attributes, but each time i edit the whole thing, my nested models are not updated, they are 'cloned'. let me give you an example. lets we have nested models which have string column, and right now its value is "A".
we decide we want it to be "B", and click update. what we get is two models, one with "A", and the other with "B". Then we change "A" into B again. we get "A", "B", "B", "B". Each time i try to update, i have 2x more models. it sucks.(to make it more clear i can tell that the doubled fields are the one i want)
i have determined it is somehow fault of `assign_attributes() & save!` or `update_attributes!()` methods, but i know that with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` it shouldnt work like that. Here is the necessary code:

Posters controller (Poster is the model which has those associated models with it)

```
  def edit
    PosterCreator.new(@poster)
  end  

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @poster.update_attributes(poster_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @poster }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end 
    end 
  end

def poster_params
    params.require(:poster).permit(:content, :title, :category_id, string_fields_attributes: [:detail, :field_id], float_fields_attributes: [:float_number, :field_id], integer_fields_attributes: [:integer_number, :field_id], text_fields_attributes: [:description, :field_id], date_fields_attributes: [:date, :field_id])
end
```

Here's the PosterCreator concern i use in "edit" action

```
class PosterCreator

  attr_accessor :poster

  def initialize(poster)
    @poster = poster
    build_fields_based_on_category
  end

  private

  def build_fields_based_on_category
    @poster.category.fields.each do |field|
      unless list_all_field_ids.include?(field.id)
        @custom_field = @poster.send("#{field.kind}_fields").build
        @custom_field.source = field
##########little explanation. Field model has kind, which can be integer, text, date etc, based on it, proper fields for poster are built
      end
    end    
  end 

  def list_all_field_ids
    @poster.list_fields.map do |field|
      field.field_id
    end  
  end

end
```

And finally Poster class:

```
class Poster < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :text_fields
  has_many :string_fields
  has_many :integer_fields
  has_many :float_fields
  has_many :date_fields

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :float_fields
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :integer_fields
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :text_fields
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :string_fields
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :date_fields

  def list_fields
    fields = []
    self.text_fields.each { |field| fields << field }
    self.string_fields.each { |field| fields << field }
    self.integer_fields.each { |field| fields << field }
    self.date_fields.each { |field| fields << field }
    self.float_fields.each { |field| fields << field }
    fields
  end  

end
```

Also poster_form might be helpful:

```
= simple_form_for @poster do |f|
    = f.input :category_id, collection: Category.all, prompt: "Choose category"
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :content
    = f.simple_fields_for :string_fields do |fsf|
        = fsf.input :detail
        = fsf.input :field_id, as: :hidden
    = f.simple_fields_for :text_fields do |ftf|
        = ftf.input :description
        = ftf.input :field_id, as: :hidden
    = f.simple_fields_for :integer_fields do |fif|
        = fif.input :integer_number 
        = fif.input :field_id, as: :hidden
    = f.simple_fields_for :float_fields do |fff|
        = fff.input :float_number
        = fff.input :field_id, as: :hidden
    = f.simple_fields_for   :date_fields do |fdf|
        = fdf.input :date
        = fdf.input :field_id, as: :hidden
    = f.submit
```

Thats a lot of code, but i hope someone will be able to tell me why it is not working the way it should

Comment: Try removing all the hidden :field_id inputs in the form.

Comment: Ditto - I don't think you need `field_id` for every `fields_for`, Rails should input that automatically

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two things, :id and :_destroy to each nested model in your poster controller, i.e: `string_fields_attributes: [:id, :detail, :field_id, :_destroy]`.

You will need to add these fields for all nested models.
This will allow your controller to identify if the changes were made to an already existing model (thus not creating a new one), and it gives the posters_controller the ability to destroy records.

You also need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :string_fields, allow_destroy: true` in your poster.rb